# How to use sliding window on Oracle table?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sliding-window

I have a table (records) getting real-time in Oracle. I need to extract data from this table and count number of entries added to the database in every minute. This statistics is then dumped to the new table 'statistics'. How can I effectively extract data in sliding window fashion?

Structure of Table:

```
RecordId       NUMBER(10)    ---- Unique random value for every row        
RecordTime     VARCHAR2(64)  ---- Timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS
```

The query should be something similar to:

```
select substr(RecordTime, 1, 16), count(*) 
from Records 
group by substr(RecordTime, 1, 16);
```

Every minute around 500000 new rows are expected in the table, so I need to sliding window operation on this database table. If a queue-like operation is better, then please let me know about this as well.

Comment: Why on earth do you store timestamp values as VARCHAR2?

Comment: Why doesn't your query do what you want?  It seems to be exactly what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be better to have the `RecordTime` as a date field so that you could create an index on it and query it. Using `substr()` you'd be missing out on that.

Second, a time series database like `Influx` is more suitable for this use case. You might consider using it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Point 1 is really appreciable, I will keep that in mind. But I really cannot change the database and cannot use another framework. If that so, considering such a big volume, I believe, Apache Spark is the best option. I can even handle heavy data operations in the future. So could you please let me know if a similar operation can be done using Oracle?

Comment: You can certainly set up spark if you have several other analytical use cases in mind. Results may be persisted in a columnar datastore like Cassandra. The results may be stored in Oracle also, but that depends on what you have in mind.

Comment: Also, your recordId is `Number(10)`. And because you are expecting `500_000 records per minute`, you'll start seeing non unique `recordId`s in approximately 14 days.

Comment: I am only allowed to use Oracle for this task. So is it possible to extract values from Oracle table in queue or sliding window fashion? If yes, could you please elaborate on that part? And right now, being in the testing phase, 15 days worth of data is quite sufficient.

Comment: You can maintain an offset `last_read_till` somewhere. In each iteration read a certain number of records from this timestamp and update it with the `recordTime` of the most recent record (Assuming that the `recordTime` always increases)